# axios post with array and string together

Tags: axios

I am trying to send array and string together but it does not work. Only name is sent. images array is empty.

Can you advise way to do it?

```
axios.post('/user', {
  images: this.form,
  name: 'Fred',
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
 });
```

I did like this too, but only this.form was sent.

```
axios.post('/user', this.form, this.name)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: does `this.form` has data?

Comment: yes array for images. using form: new FormData